# How to run pytest with mysql docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, travis-ci

#### What I want to do

I have been trying to follow instructions from my travis-ci environment on [using-a-docker-image-from-a-repository-in-a-build](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#using-a-docker-image-from-a-repository-in-a-build).

In my case, and forgive my if I misspeak because I'm not too familiar with docker, I want to start a docker container with a mysql instance that I can use during `pytest`.

#### What I've tried

**.travis.yml**

```yaml
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"

cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/"

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  ...

install:
  ...
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

script:
  - docker pull mysql/mysql-server
  - docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysql; pip install -r requirements.txt;"
  - docker run mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "ls -l /root; cd /root/mysql; pytest"
```

**travis-ci logging**

```sh
$ docker pull mysql/mysql-server
Using default tag: la[secure]
la[secure]: Pulling from mysql/mysql-server
0e690826fc6e: Pulling fs layer
0e6c49086d52: Pulling fs layer
862ba7a26325: Pulling fs layer
7731c802ed08: Pulling fs layer
7731c802ed08: Waiting
862ba7a26325: Verifying Checksum
862ba7a26325: Download complete
7731c802ed08: Verifying Checksum
7731c802ed08: Download complete
0e690826fc6e: Verifying Checksum
0e690826fc6e: Download complete
0e6c49086d52: Verifying Checksum
0e6c49086d52: Download complete
0e690826fc6e: Pull complete
0e6c49086d52: Pull complete
862ba7a26325: Pull complete
7731c802ed08: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a82ff720911b2fd40a425fd7141f75d7c68fb9815ec3e5a5a881a8eb49677087
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql/mysql-server:la[secure]
The command "docker pull mysql/mysql-server" exited with 0.
2.49s$ docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysql; pip install -r requirements.txt;"
bfba9cb26b8902682903d8a5576e805e86823096220e723da0df6a6a881c1ef7
The command "docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysql; pip install -r requirements.txt;"" exited with 0.
0.74s$ docker run mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "ls -l /root; cd /root/mysql; py[secure]"
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.20-1.1.16
total 0
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /root/mysql: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: py[secure]: command not found
The command "docker run mysql/mysql-server /bin/sh -c "ls -l /root; cd /root/mysql; py[secure]"" exited with 127.
```

So it seems like for whatever reason my use case for mysql differs from the example provided by travis-ci. The specific issue seems to be that the directory `/root/mysql` just disappears so when I try the second `docker run` I get `No such file or directory`.

To be perfectly honest I don't know much about what is happening, so any help with dockerizing my pytests would be great! Also, if it's possible, I'm also curious if it's possible to move the docker logic into a `Dockerfile` of some sort.

Here is my main script where I've set it up to connect to a mysql database, so the environment variables would just need to be set appropriately, which is why I thought a `Dockerfile` might be helpful.

**main.py**

```py
    elif env == "test":
        return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
                drivername="mysql+pymysql",
                username=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
                password=os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
                host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
                port=3306,
                database=PRIMARY_TABLE_NAME
            ),
            pool_size=5,
            max_overflow=2,
            pool_timeout=30,
            pool_recycle=1800
        )
```